# How to select next 4 consecutive rows from my resultant row?

Tags: mysql

I want to know, how can i select next 4 consecutive rows along with the resultant row in MySQL?

To explain:-

i have following rows in table abc

```
name | amount 

 a   -  1000

 b   -  2000

 c   -  3000

 d   -  4000

 e   -  5000

 f   -  6000
```

Now, 
if my selection criteria is name = a , then resultant rows returned should be

```
 a   -  1000

 b   -  2000

 c   -  3000

 d   -  4000

 e   -  5000
```

In other words i want a query which will return result of query - "select * from abc where name = 'a'" plus next 4 consecutive rows to that row?

Comment: simply use limit EX:  SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name order by name
LIMIT 5 ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   abc.*
FROM     abc JOIN (SELECT amount FROM abc WHERE name = 'a') t
WHERE    abc.amount >= t.amount
ORDER BY abc.amount
LIMIT    5
```

Comment: Your answer partly answers my question however data i used in example is just for presentation. what if there is no logical connection in between values present under column name?

Comment: in your answer you mentioned that 'AND name > = 'a' ', consider my selection criteria is z and table contains following rows                z   -  1000

 q   -  2000

 c   -  3000

 r   -  4000

 w   -  5000

Comment: No no...that's what my point is, i don't want any extra condition apart from my criteria .....it's simply select matching row and without any condition or criteria next 4 consecutive rows....

Comment: in oracle we can select rows based on row num ...i want something like following query in oracle - select * from abc where rownum between (select row num from abc where name = 'a') and (select rownum+5 from abc where name = 'a')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18246/discussion-between-mangesh-jogade-and-eggyal)

Answer (score 0):

try

for mssql: `select top 5 * from abc where name > 'a' order by name`

for mysql: `select * from abc where name > 'a' order by name limit 5`

Comment: Returning TOP N Records for Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Sybase and Firebird http://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm

Comment: i want query not return any row if there is no row present in table with 'name = a'....it is just return a qualifying row plus next consecutive 4 rows.